# C - Sort two arrays the same way

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

So I have two arrays (pointers actually), lets call them `a` and `b`. I want to first sort `a`, then save the exact swaps I did to get that sorted array and apply them to my vector `b`. Here's a short example of what I mean:

```
int *a, *b;
//appropriate mallocs
a[0] = 2; a[1] = 3; a[2] = 1;
b[0] = 4; b[1] = 2; b[2] = 3;
//sort a in decreasing order --> a==[3, 2, 1]
//sort b based on sorting of a --> b==[2, 4, 3]
```

How I could achieve this without writing my own sort function?

Comment: use the standard function **[qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/)** for this

Comment: `arrays (pointers actually)`....smells trouble.

Comment: Do you really have to sort one array first and then apply the same transformation to the other array afterwards, or can you do them at the same time?

Comment: Do you have to deal with primitive data type ? What about a struct wich keeps the last place in the array ?

Comment: Create a third array - array of indexes into `a` - filled initially with `0 .. countof(a)`. In compare function, compare the elements of `a` using the indexes. After the `qsort` is finished, the third array would contain the new order of the elements, which you can apply to both `a` and `b`.

Comment: I would perform swaps in both arrays at the same time.

Comment: How big are your arrays?

Comment: @molbdnilo They can be sorted at the same time

Comment: @Dummy00001 Could you expand on how I would do this? Sounds like a great solution

Comment: @TravisGriggs Small (~100 elements at most), but not allocating more memory than required (at least for longer periods of time) is part of the task.

Comment: Be wary that a given algorithm would probably perform more swaps than would be optimal - for qsort, elements are moved to particular halves, not necessarily to the correct location.

Comment: @BeastEye, the idea is the same as in the accepted answer, but instead of pointer, I often prefer to use the indexes. Also, a side bonus, is that you can make the sort stable (the original intent of the trick) if elements are equal, you additionally compare the indexes (or pointers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The better solution is to group the data into an array of structures, then sort that based on the desired key (i.e. the `a` values):

```
struct my_data {
  int a;
  int b;
};

struct my_data data[100];

static int data_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  const struct my_data *da = a, *db = b;

  return da->a < db->a ? -1 : da->a > db->a;
}

qsort(data, sizeof data / sizeof *data, sizeof *data, data_cmp);
```

This uses [`qsort()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) to sort, which is typically highly desirable.

Comment: Nice one, but not applicable if you have to deal with distinct arrays.

Comment: `return da->a - db->a;` is more efficient.

Comment: @ElderBug: Yeah, and prone to overflows.

Comment: @ElderBug I never use that, it's ill-defined if there is a risk for numerical overflow.

Comment: @Amessihel You can re-wrap the data as array of structure, sort, then unwrap. It'll perhaps be costly, but also might not be and saves you from re-implementing sort just to extract the swaps.

Comment: This will take quite a few changes, but I should be able to pull it off. Thanks!

Comment: @rcgldr No, that would be `sizeof (struct data *)`, which is completely different. The expression `*data` has type `struct data` which is the thing you want the size of.

Comment: @unwind - The answer I gave avoids having to put multiple (2 or more) arrays into a common structure. There is an overhead in creating an array of pointers, but sort doesn't have to be re-implemented, just sort the array of pointers with a compare routine that uses the pointers. The post sort reorder in place is only O(n), or the arrays could be copied to buffers according to the pointers (in my example, (pa[i]-a) converts a pointer into an index).

Answer (score 10):

This example does what the original question asked for, it sorts two (or more) arrays the same way, without having to combine the array elements into a common structure.

It uses an array of pointers, so the compare function does not need to know which array it is sorting, only the type of the elements being sorted. It could be modified to sort multiple arrays according to one of the arrays.

It creates an array of pointers to `a[]`, uses `qsort()` to sort the array of pointers according to `a[]`, then uses the sorted pointers to reorder both `a[]` and `b[]` in place (with the side effect that the sorted pointers are restored to their initial state).

The reordering time complexity is O(n) as each store places an element in its sorted position.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare(const void *pp0, const void *pp1)
{
    int i0 = **(int **)pp0;
    int i1 = **(int **)pp1;
    if(i0 > i1)return -1;
    if(i0 < i1)return  1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a[3] = {2, 3, 1};
    int b[3] = {4, 3, 2};
    int *pa[3];
    size_t i, j, k;
    int ta, tb;

    /* create array of pointers to a[] */
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
        pa[i] = &a[i];

    /* sort array of pointers */
    qsort(pa, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(pa[0]), compare);

    /* reorder a[] and b[] according to the array of pointers */
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++){
        if(i != pa[i]-a){
            ta = a[i];
            tb = b[i];
            k = i;
            while(i != (j = pa[k]-a)){
                a[k] = a[j];
                b[k] = b[j];
                pa[k] = &a[k];
                k = j;
            }
            a[k] = ta;
            b[k] = tb;
            pa[k] = &a[k];
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
        printf("%2d ", a[i]);
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
        printf("%2d ", b[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Deleted my answer to highlight yours.

Comment: +1 for the amazing answer -2 for the variable names in the loop. Just kidding it's just a +1. variable names got me super confused though.

Comment: @AdamZahran -  In compare(), the names are pp? to indicate they are pointers to pointers. In main, pa means pointer to a, ta and tb are temps for a[] and b[]

Answer (score 1):

This is not solvable as requested, the sort functions don't expose the swaps they perform.

However, it seems that the result could be achieved with a struct.

```
struct combined {
   int a_;
   int b_;
};
```

Where the `qsort` function tests the `a_` element, but also sorts the `b_` data.
Again, this requires a comparison function

```
 int compare( const void * l, const void * r )
 {
     struct combined * _l= (struct combined *)l;
     struct combined * _r= (struct combined *)r;
     if( _l->a_ > _r->a_ ) return -1; // reverse sort
     if( _l->a_ < _r->a_ ) return 1;
     return 0;
 }
```

finally

```
 struct combined array[] = { {2,4}, {3,2}, {1,3} };
 qsort( array, 3, sizeof( struct combined), compare );

 array => { {3,2}, {2,4}, {1,3} };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// i am going to submit the idea not the code.

    int *a,*b;
    int *ord; // an array that holds indexes (sorting orders)

//...

    a[ord[0]] = 2; a[ord[1]] = 3; a[ord[2]] = 1;
    b[ord[0]] = 4; b[ord[1]] = 2; b[ord[2]] = 3;

//...
//now you have just to sort the indexes array ord
```