# How to sort a table according to the order of another by "mirror effect"?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I know there are already a lot of answers to this on SO (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948281/c-sort-two-arrays-the-same-way)), but before to close this post, I would like to have an answer to my question.

I have an array that has a relationship with the order of another array, for example: `A=[1, 0, 2]` and `B=[4, 1, 3]`. I would like to sort array `A` and keep the order of `B` relative to `A` (in the context of my work, the two arrays are the left and right values of an "arrow", so here: `1 0 2 -> 4 1 3`). The result will be as follows: `A=[0, 1, 2]` and B keep the order defined by `A`: `B=[1, 4, 3]`.

The code I use is:

```
struct Combined
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

int cmp(void *a, void *b)
{
    struct Combined *x = (struct Combined *)a;
    struct Combined *y = (struct Combined *)b;

    return x->a - y->a;
}

void order(int *left, int len1, int *right, int len2)
{
    // The two tables are not always of same size 
    unsigned int len = max(len1, len2);
    struct Combined *combined = malloc(len * sizeof(struct Combined));

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < len1; i++)
        combined[i].a = left[i];

    for (i = 0; i < len2; i++)
        combined[i].b = right[i];

    // We sort 'combined' according to the first table only
    qsort(combined, len, sizeof(struct Combined), cmp);

    // The values are then reassigned

    for (i = 0; i < len1; i++)
        left[i] = combined[i].a;

    for (i = 0; i < len2; i++)
        right[i] = combined[i].b;

    free(combined);
}
```

I'm pretty sure it works, but I've noticed a behaviour I don't want: when arrays `A` and `B` are the same but reversed, then, once the sorting is done, the two resulting arrays are no longer the inverse of each other, so I imagine that the algorithm I'm using is not the one I want (hence "mirror effect" in the title).

To illustrate, if `A=[1, 2, 0]` and `B=[0, 2, 1]`, the resulting will be `A=[0, 1, 2]` and `B=[1, 0, 2]`. But I want `B=[2, 1, 0]`...

How to adapt this algorithm to such a behaviour while remaining general with respect to any two tables?

**EDIT**

Here is a more abstract but contextual explanation of what I want to achieve:

In my programme, I manipulate "arrows". This is a data structure that represents an input as a series of numbers and represents an output as a series of the same numbers (but in any order).

The processes that manipulate these arrows can perform all sorts of tasks often leading to a result that is not spontaneously intuitive to read because the different numbers are not always sorted at the end of them.

To illustrate, a resulting arrow may have the following form: `1 2 0 -> 0 2 1`. In this example, we can see that the output is the inverse of the input; another example: `2 0 1 -> 1 2 0` (and there is no particular relationship between the two sets of numbers).

To make the result easier to read, I would like to be able to reorder the numbers so that the input is easy to read (i.e. sorted) and of course keeping the same relationship to the output. The easiest way to do this seemed to be the way I presented above, but, as said above and in the comments, this relationship between inpout and output is no longer preserved as I would like. The question is therefore how to modify this algorithm to achieve the desired result.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  [1,0,2] is the correctly sorted B. It has kept the same order in relation to A. A0->B1, A1->B0, A2->B2 before and after.

Comment: Indeed, it is correct according to the algorithm used, however, in the context I am using it, this result is not correct because the inversion relation of the two arrays is not preserved, therefore my question is more of an algorithmic nature, namely how to modify this code in order to preserve the inversion in the particular case where the arrays are inverted from each other. I could check this quite trivially, but perhaps there is a name for what I am trying to do, or another method...

Comment: You seem to want two different answers.  One is to sort the arrays in parallel, using the keys from array A.  The second is to sort the two arrays independently, eliminating the relationship between the two.  Pick one.  You can't have both.  In your last example, if `A` is sorted to `[0, 1, 2]` and `B` is sorted to `[2, 1, 0]`, then the mapping between the two arrays is not preserved.  E.g., `1` -> `0` becomes `1` -> `1`.  So, organize your thoughts, decide what you want, *then* determine if you need help to achieve it.  At present, you don't know what you want, so there is no question.

Comment: FWIW, the short answer to the second version of your question is simple:  Sort array `A` in ascending order, and sort array `B` in descending order.  It's up to you to decide which version you want.

Comment: I think you need to explain what an inverse relationship is. Does it mean that B[A[i]] == i? Because that is not what happens in the [4,1,3] example. Does it mean that A goes up and B goes down? Because for that, you would sort each array separately.

Comment: In the [4,1,3] example it looks like you are doing what this algorithm does, but nobody here can understand why you want [1,4,3] in the first example and you don't want [1,0,2] in the second example

Comment: Re "*The two tables are not always of same size*", Your solution doesn't work, then. In fact, what you are trying to do makes no sense. What output do expect for `a = { 3,2,1,0 }` and `b = { 2,1,0 }`? The current result is `{ {0,uninitialize}, {1,0}, {2,1}, {3,2} }`, so you end up with `a = { 0,1,2,3 }` and `b = { undefined_behaviour,0,1 }`

Comment: I don't think you are explaining what you want very well. Do you want a new routine that looks similar to your original routine, or do you want your original routine to somehow magically detect it needs to perform mirror transformations instead?

Comment: I have edited the question to show the context of what I want, I hope it is clearer... If it still isn't, then what I want is, as some have said, not clear enough for me either and we can close the question.

Comment: You are sorting arrows, so len1 **must be** equal to len2. (there are no arrows without a head or without a tail). So, you only need the array of `combined` structs, and you can omit the separate arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the question assumed that the approach used was in the right direction for the context mentioned, but this is not the case, because, as stated in the comments and in @jxh 's answer, this method assumes that the tables are of the same length and furthermore involves an intermediate structure.
So I present here an alternative way of doing things that meets *the context*.

The aim being to reorder the elements of the two arrays in the same logical order, it is sufficient to sort the first array and then create a new array which, for each new value, will check which one was in the original location and replace it with the value from the first sorted array if it exists (if not, the original value from the second array is placed).

Here is the function:

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const int *A = a;
    const int *B = b;
    return (*A > *B) - (*A < *B);
}

void order(int *left, int len1, int *right, int len2)
{
    int *sortedLeft = malloc(len1 * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(sortedLeft, left, len1 * sizeof(int));
    qsort(sortedInames, len1, sizeof(int), cmp);

    int *rightOrdered = malloc(len2 * sizeof(int));
    
    for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++)
    {
        bool assigned = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < len1; j++)
        {
            if (right[i] == left[j])
            {
                rightOrdered[i] = leftSorted[j];
                assigned = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!assigned)
            rightOrdered[i] = right[i];
    }

    memcpy(left, leftSorted, len1 * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(right, rightOrdered, len2 * sizeof(int));
    
    free(sortedLeft);
    free(rightOrdered);
}
```

Comment: Assumes the arrays do not contain repeated values. But, if this works for you, good job!

Answer (score 1):

You can create the "mirror effect" as you call it by mapping the index to the mirror index.

If you don't want the mirror effect, the mapping index of `i` is the identity, `i`. If you want the mirror effect, the mapping index of `i` would be `(len - 1 - i)`.

```
#define MAP(I, LEN, MIRROR)  \
        ((MIRROR)            \
         ? ((LEN) - 1 - (I)) \
         : (I))
```

Then, before sorting, when creating the `combined` array, use the mapping for the `right`.

```
for (i = 0; i < len2; i++)
    combined[i].b = right[MAP(i, len2, mirror)];
```

And after sorting, use the mapping when restoring `right`.

```
for (i = 0; i < len2; i++)
    right[i] = combined[MAP(i, len2, mirror)].b;
```

---

#### How it works

When `mirror` is true, `combined` associates `left[i]` with `right[len2 - 1 - i]`. So, when sorting, the mirror of `right` is what gets re-ordered as `left` is sorted. After sorting, `right` needs to be restored, but it is the contents of `combined` need to be mirrored back.

#### Caveats

The routine works fine if `left` and `right` have the same number of elements. However, if they do not, strange effects might occur. When `len2` is smaller, some of the associated values of `right` might be associated to values in `left` that are beyond `len2`, and `combined` is left containing uninitialized values. When `len2` is larger, the elements of `right` beyond `len1` will not get sorted.